# Pass additional parameters to pagination url

Tags: yii

Im using CArrayDataProvider for pagination. Now only page numbers are passed in url. I want to pass some more additional attributes. How do I do that? Here is my dataprovider.

```
$dataProvider = new CArrayDataProvider($arrayData,  array(
                                'keyField'=>'entity_id',
                                'sort'=>array(
                                        'attributes'=>array('entity_id'),
                                        'defaultOrder'=>array('entity_id' => false),
                                ),
                                'pagination'=>array(
                                        'pageSize'=>20,
                                ),
        ));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CPagination takes params. Try adding `'params' => array('foo' => 'bar')` in  `pagination`.

Answer (score 7):

The question was how to pass "additional" parameters.

The code of the accepted answer will override your existing $_GET parameters:

```
    'params'  => array('foo' => 'bar')
```

To add "additional" parameters, first add them to existing $_GET parameters:

```
    $pagerparams = $_GET; 
    $pagerparams['foo'] = 'bar';

    $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'pagination'=>array(
            'params'  => $pagerparams,
        ),
        ...
    ));
```

Comment: Thanks, even if it didn't help OP it helped me